# Show / Hide Datepicker with Radio Buttons

Tags: jquery, html, datepicker

i am creating a booking form where i want the customer to select between two options from a Radio Box. Both of the Radio Boxes are going to display its own datepicker.

The problem i've got. I cannot figure out how to hide it on load, i've tried numerous ways such as hiding it with a Div, trying to hide it with CSS etc.

So my question is how do i hide it on load, and how do i show each datepicker depending on which Radio Button is checked. And if one is selected, and want to select the other one, the previous one get hidden and the checked one is displayed.

My Code HTML Code:

```
 <tr><td> Velg lengde av bookingen: </tr></td>
<tr><td> <label for="timer">En til flere timer</label> <input type="radio" id="radiotimer" name="lengde" value="Timer">
       <label for="dager">En til flere dager</label><input type="radio" id=" radiodager" name="lengde" value="Dager"></tr></td>

<div class="VisDatoValg">
<script>valgavdato() </script>
  <tr><td><label for="from">Book fra:</label></tr></td>
<tr><td><input type="text" id="fra" name="Fra"></tr></td>
  <tr><td><label for="to">Book til</label></tr></td>
<tr><td>  <input type="text" id="til" name="Til"></tr></td>
  </div>
```

My Javascript code:

```
$( function valgavdato() {
var dateFormat = "mm/dd/yy",
    to_MaxDate = 13;    // From date + this = to maxDate

    from = $( "#fra" )
.datepicker({
    minDate: '0+',
    defaultDate: "+1w",
    changeMonth: true,
    numberOfMonths: 1
})
.on( "change", function() {
    var PickedDate = getDate( this );
    // See that date is in UTC format.
    console.log( "From DatePicker: "+JSON.stringify(PickedDate) );

    // Process the picked date.
    var tempDay = PickedDate.getDate() + to_MaxDate; // Add a number of days to the picked date.
    var tempMonth = PickedDate.getMonth() + 1;   // Because months are zero based.
    var tempYear = PickedDate.getYear() + 1900; // Because years are 1900 based
    console.log( "Temp date: "+ tempYear+"/"+tempMonth+"/"+tempDay +" --- It may look impossible... But Date() handles it.");

    // Create a date object in a UTC format.
  var newMaxDate = new Date(Date.UTC(tempYear, tempMonth-1, tempDay, 0, 0, 0));
    console.log(  "New max date: : "+ JSON.stringify(newMaxDate) );

    // Set the minDate ans maxDate options.
    to.datepicker( "option", {"minDate": PickedDate, "maxDate": newMaxDate});

}),
    to = $( "#til" ).datepicker({
        maxDate: '14+',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1
    })
.on( "change", function() {
    from.datepicker( "option", "maxDate", getDate( this ) );
});

function getDate( element ) {
    var date;
    try {
        date = $.datepicker.parseDate( dateFormat, element.value );
    } catch( error ) {
        date = null;
    }

    return date;
}
```

} );

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap your datepickers with a class or id, such as the following:

```
 <div class="datepicker1"><tr><td><label for="from">Book fra:</label></tr></td>
 <tr><td><input type="text" id="fra" name="Fra"></tr></td></div>
 <div class="datepicker2">
 <tr><td><label for="to">Book til</label></tr></td>
 <tr><td>  <input type="text" id="til" name="Til"></tr></td>
 </div>
```

In your CSS, you want something like the following:

```
 .datepicker1, .datepicker2 {
     display: none;
    }
```

In javascript, you want:

```
    $.('#radiotimer').click(function() {
        $.('.datepicker1').show();
        $.('.datepicker2').hide();
    }
    $.('#dagertimer').click(function() {
        $.('.datepicker2').show();
        $.('.datepicker1').hide();
    }
```

This is a very simplistic example of the direction you should be looking at, so you probably want to expand it more. I would also look at rewriting your html to make more sense. That said, my answer here should work for what you are attempting to do.